# Override bulma variables in vue components without increasing payload size - Nuxt

Tags: sass, vuejs2, nuxt.js, bulma

I have a main.scss file in my assets folder which I use to override bulma variables. I make this file available globally via the nuxt-config file.

```
@import '~bulma/sass/utilities/initial-variables';
@import '~bulma/sass/utilities/functions';

//override some variables
$primary: #FF5B5B;
$light: #f1f1f1;

@import '~bulma';

$section-height: calc(100vh - #{$navbar-height});
```

However, I also need to override variables after the `@import '~bulma';` statement. The problem here is that this vastly increases the payload size of the site when using theses variables in vue components.

For every component where I need to use these variables like this:

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
@import "~/assets/css/main.scss";

.custom-height {
  height: $section-height;
}

</style>
```

About 1 MB is added. How can I only import '~bulma' once? I tried creating separate files, one for variables after importing bulma, and one for variables after importing bulma, however this doesn't work because you have to import bulma anyway in the second file because otherwise you couldn't reference these variables.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you can avoid importing your main.scss file in every componente with this package: [Nuxt Style Resources](https://github.com/nuxt-community/style-resources-module)

1st step: make sure you have sass-loader and node-sass installed as dev dependencies or install them: `yarn add sass-loader node-sass --save-dev`or `npm i sass-loader node-sass --save-dev`

2nd step: install Nuxt Style Resources as a dependency: `yarn add @nuxtjs/style-resources`or `npm i @nuxtjs/style-resources`

3rd step: add it to nuxt.config.js

```
export default {
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/style-resources'],
  styleResources: {
    scss: [
      './assets/vars/*.scss',
      './assets/abstracts/_mixins.scss' // use underscore "_" & also file extension ".scss"
      ]
  }
}
```

For more info check the package docs on the link above.

Answer (score 0):

this sound like a typical usecase for a plugin. I did almost the same, but with vuetify instead of bulma.
If you only want to include a css file globaly all you need to do is to add this in the property css of your nuxt.config.js file.

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  css: ['~/assets/css/main.scss'],
  ...
}
```

You will probably need a loader for scss.
If you need to configure your bulma first, you could consider to create a plugin.
In the plugin folder create a file bulma.js then put all your config stuff in this file.

```
import Bulma from 'bulma'
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.use(Bulma, { your config goes here })
```

If you need to access variables from your app write in the same file:

```
export default ({ app, store ... }) => {
  // now you can use all the context
}
```

All available context attributes can be found here:
[Nuxtjs context](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context)

After this you need to include it as plugin in nuxt.config.js.

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: ['~/plugins/bulma']
  build: {
    vendor: ['bulma'] // from node_modules imported only once for the whole app
  }
  ...
}
```

All things you put in build.vendor is loaded only **ONCE**. [Nuxt build vendor](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins)
Hope this will help. :)