# Importing SASS variables into Vue component

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, bulma

I'm working on building a webpage using Vue, Typescript, Webpack, and Bulma. I got everything working and building correctly but I noticed that some of my bundles were massive (over 2mb in some cases). After a lot of confusion I figured out it was because I was importing my main SCCS file that included Bulma, Bulma Fluent, and Material Design Icons into my components so that I could use the variables, mixins, and extend some of the classes. From what I understand `@import` simply copies everything from the import, which would explain my massive bundles.

A close approximation of my working code:

*main.scss*

```
/*Color customizations*/

@import "bulma-fluent/bulma.sass";
@import "buefy/src/scss/buefy";
@import "@mdi/font/scss/materialdesignicons";

/*Some custom classes*/
```

*MyComponent.vue*

```
/*Template and Script here*/
<style scoped lang="scss">
    @import "./main.scss";

    .floating {
        @extend .m-1;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    @include mobile {
        .floating {
            max-width: unset;
            left: 0;
        }
    }
</style>
```

I want to be able to reference classes/variables/mixins from my `main.scss` without it ballooning the size of my modules. I thought about creating a separate `variables.sass` file but I couldn't get that to work plus it doesn't fix the issue of extending styles. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765343/override-bulma-variables-in-vue-components-without-increasing-payload-size-nux) question but I'm not using Nuxt.

How can I get this working?

P.S. I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to Webpack/Vue/SASS/SCSS so I apologize if I'm just being dumb here.

**Edit**

In the end I split out the variables to their own file and imported those globally. It doesn't solve the use case of extending styles but I think that's a lost cause. My code is below:

*Variables.scss*

```
/*Customization here*/
@import "bulma/sass/utilities/functions.sass";

@import "bulma-fluent/src/sass/color/_all.sass";

@import "bulma/sass/utilities/initial-variables.sass";
@import "bulma/sass/utilities/derived-variables.sass";
@import "bulma/sass/utilities/mixins.sass";
```

*Main.scss*

```
@import "./Variables.scss";

@import "bulma-fluent/bulma.sass";
@import "buefy/src/scss/buefy";
@import "@mdi/font/scss/materialdesignicons";

/*Some custom classes*/
```

*webpack.js*

```
/*Other irrelevant configurations*/
{
    test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
    use: [
        "vue-style-loader",
        "css-loader",
        {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
                additionalData: `
                @import "./Variables.scss";
                `
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

*MyComponent.vue*

```
/*Template and Script here*/
<style scoped lang="scss">
    .floating {
        margin: $size-1;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    @include mobile {
        .floating {
            max-width: unset;
            left: 0;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: is this based on Vue CLI? If yes, then there should be guides here https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#automatic-imports

Comment: This isn't using the CLI but it looks like that could be configurable outside the CLI. Would this be any different than importing the SCSS file? Would it stop the bundles from getting so large?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use the same stack. I have `variables.scss` file with variables and bulma mixins and that `variables.scss` file is imported only in `main.scss` .
To make all variables and mixins available in all components without using `@import` in `style` section you should add `loaderOptions` section to `vue.config.js` file. Here is my `vue.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        prependData: '@import "~@/assets/scss/_variables.scss";'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this any different than just putting the import in the style manually? I tried that but it gave me all sorts of errors when I tried to build

Comment: I think that there is difference. That way of making variables available globally in project is described in official docs. https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#passing-options-to-pre-processor-loaders
And it is strange that you have errors while building. Make sure you imported ```variables.scss``` file in ```main.scss``` file and the path you wrote in ```prependData``` is correct. You also could take a look at my project, maybe that would help. https://github.com/eduardmavliutov/videogame-quiz

Comment: I decided to give it a try again and I'm not getting build errors, I must have done something wrong. Thanks for sharing your project, having a good example helps a lot!